# What is difference between running the commands ansible and ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

When looking at examples for how to define and run ansible scripts, some examples use 'ansible' command to execute the scripts and some examples use 'ansible-playbook' command.  But I have been unable to find the difference between them or guidelines regarding which one to use when.

What are the differences between the two commands?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ansible scripts are called `playbooks`.

By definition

> A playbook is a list of plays. A play is minimally a mapping between a
> set of hosts selected by a host specifier (usually chosen by groups
> but sometimes by hostname globs) and the tasks which run on those
> hosts to define the role that those systems will perform. There can be
> one or many plays in a playbook.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-plays

Then, you execute your playbooks with the command `ansible-playbook`, for example this command execute the playbook `test.yml` on `all` servers in your `inventory` file:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -i inventory all
```

with `ansible` command you can execute just a tasks against your servers, for example this command execute a task with the module `ping` on `all` servers in your `inventory` file:

```
ansible -m ping -i inventory all
```

Then the difference is with `ansible-playbook` you can execute a playbook with a lot of tasks and with `ansible` you just can execute a task.

Welcome to ansible world. Red Hat offers an introductory course of ansible you can take it, It'll help you a lot.

https://www.redhat.com/en/services/training/do007-ansible-essentials-simplicity-automation-technical-overview

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation of the difference.  The explanation does match the way I have seen it being used.

Comment: I clearly understand the functionality of the two commands, but the *intention* for the separation remains misty for me. Please correct me, but the use case of `ansible` is just a special case for `ansible-playbook` (which would require a single extra command switch), but happens far more seldom compared to `ansible-playbook` which is very awkward to type.

Comment: With `ansible-playbook` comman you can excecute a playbook with one o more `tasks` (each task execute one module), with `ansible` command you can execute just one `task`. You could say that the `ansible` command serves to execute only one task.